# How do I calculate the proportion of one value in a variable to use in a line graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, percentage

I am working with a Supreme Court dataset. I am trying to visualize the percentage of cases in each term that were decided by a one-vote margin. I have variables for terms, the number of votes in the majority, and the number of votes in the minority. The best option for visualization is a line graph with terms as the x-axis and the percentage of decisions made with a one-vote margin as the y-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
scdby %>%
  select(majVotes, minVotes, term)
```

I created a new variable for the vote margin.

```
scdbv %>%
 select(majVotes, minVotes, term) %>%
 mutate(margin = majVotes - minVotes)
```

Since then, I feel like I have tried every method under the sun to get the percent of single margin votes to apply in ggplot for my graph. This is the most recent method:

```
scdbv %>%
  select(majVotes, minVotes, term) %>%
  mutate(margin = majVotes - minVotes) %>%
  mutate(margin1 = if_else(margin == "1", "1", "NA")) %>%
  mutate(margin1 = as.integer(margin1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = term)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = count(margin1) / n()))
```

Which returns:

```
  no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I am sure there is something very simple I am missing with how to do this.

Comment: Not a very important point, but if you load the tidyverse, you do not need to also load dplyr since dplyr is part of the core tidyverse packages (so it gets loaded when you load the tidyverse package)

Comment: Your `x` and `y` should be in the same `aes()`. Maybe read this to get started with using ggplot2: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
scdbv %>%
  select(majVotes, minVotes, term) %>%
  mutate(margin = majVotes - minVotes) %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  summarize(percentage=sum(margin==1)/n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(term,percentage)) +
    geom_line()
```

After creating `margin`, I group by `term`, and create a data.frame where for each term, the percentage of cases with a margin of one is `summarize`d. I then plot this new data. As noted in a comment above, your `x` and `y` are best defined already in the `ggplot()` call, and then `geom_line` can contain only stuff like color and line weight.

For example, I created this fake sample:

```
scdbv<-data.frame(majVotes=c(6,4,5,6,4,5),minVotes=c(5,2,3,3,3,4), term=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
```

and the result is (the somewhat uninspiring):

[image]

You might want to look into `theme()` to make this more appealing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote and accept! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (or just accept, since you don't have the upvote privilege yet -- but accepting gains your reputation!)